# C++ Syntax: return statement with space after "template"; what does it mean

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-interprocess

### TL;DR:

What does the following Syntax for the functions return type and the return statement mean? (Code from [`boost::interprocess`](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/blob/09784e6201a6d8703a77c9b823f1666596ce2925/include/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_memory_impl.hpp#L364))

```
template <class T>
typename segment_manager::template construct_proxy<T>::type
  construct(char_ptr_holder_t name)
  {   return mp_header->template construct<T>(name);  }
```

### Question

While trying to understand what is going on in [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15298007/258418), i came across some akward syntax:

```
//Create a new segment with given name and size
boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::create_only,
            "MySharedMemory", 65536);

//Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
const ShmemAllocator allocator(segment.get_segment_manager());

ShmVector* v = segment.construct<ShmVector>("ShmVector")(allocator);
```

In the last line a function that "retruns 'throwing' construct proxy object" ([boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/segment_manager.html#idp33794880-bb)) is called. Apparently it allows us to call this `construct proxy` with the parameters that would be passed to the constructor of `ShmVector`(template parameter). Since I could not find the documentation for the `construct proxy` I decided to take a look and found the [following code](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/blob/09784e6201a6d8703a77c9b823f1666596ce2925/include/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_memory_impl.hpp#L364):

```
template <class T>
typename segment_manager::template construct_proxy<T>::type
  construct(char_ptr_holder_t name)
  {   return mp_header->template construct<T>(name);  }
```

And here my understanding stops:

- It looks like there are two return types for the function construct, `typename segment_manager::template` and `construct_proxy<T>::type`, this does not make sense to me
- `template` is used as a class member (`segment_manager`, `mp_header`), isn't such use of keywords dissallowed?
- the functions seems to be actually returning two objects/parts:
  the syntax `return partA partB;` suggests so.

Comment: It becomes (slightly) less confusing when you realise that the whole thing could have been written as: `return mp_header -> template construct < T > ( name ) ;` That is, the spaces are largely irrelevant in the first place. It's just that, since both "template" and "construct" are formed wholly of alphabet characters, you _need_ the space there to separate them, whereas you don't with the rest. But it's still a single expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return mp_header->template construct<T>(name);
```

The keyword `template` is used to indicate that `construct` is a member template of the type of `*mp_header`. You can imagine this as:

```
return mp_header->construct<T>(name);
```

which instantiates the `construct` member function with the type `T`, calls it with `name` as an argument, then returns the result. However, C++ requires the `template` keyword here since `mp_header` has dependent type. See: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)